# Should Header files be added to the target?

Tags: c++, xcode, build

When you create a .h file, Xcode unchecks the "targets" box. But normally adds .cpp / .m / .mm files.

When should and should not a .h file be treated as a target in a build system?

Comment: I edited this to make it slightly more general since it isn't really a Xcode-specific question, and the answers would apply to other build systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because .h files are included in your source files. A "target" is something that you have to compile on its own (a "source file").

Say we have

foo.cpp

```
  #include "foo.h"

  ... 
  ...  lots more stuff here ... 
  ...

  int main()
  {
     ... some code goes here ... 
  }
```

then the compiler will compile `foo.cpp` into an object file, and using the linker component making it into an executable file.

The `foo.h` file is included in your `foo.cpp`, and gets compiled there. If we have a complex project, `bar.cpp` may also include `foo.h`, so it gets compiled in twice - this is not a problem [typically], since header files should only contain things that can be compiled into your executable many times - if that isn't the case, "you're doing it wrong".

Comment: Additionally, a file may get included twice within the same .cpp file (e.g. foo.cpp includes foo.h and bar.h, and foo.h also includes bar.h), which is also not normally a problem if you correctly use include guards.

Answer (score 3):

Source files like `.cpp` / `.m`  and  `.mm` files get compiled into binaries (usually `.obj` files).

Header files, e.g. `.h`, get `#include`ed into the source files by the C-pre-processor  (almost verbatim at the text level), and get integrated into the source file's build, so there is (generally) no need to independently compile a header file.